# Post installation error: no such device . grub rescue

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, grub

I installed ubuntu 14.04 as the only operating system on a computer with 1 hard disk and chose the following partitioning:

```
sda1 (fat32) for EFI  
sda2 (ext4) for /home  
sda3 swap  
sda4 (ext4) for /(the system installation)  
sda5 for(biosgrub) The installer said it's needed.
```

After the installation I received this error message:

```
error: no such device (a long string that is a kind of serial number).
grub rescue>
```

I tried to re install the system but received the same error.

Using `ls` in the `grub rescue` give me all of the 5 partitions.

Comment: The long string which you mention is partition's UUID number. This is a unique number gets assigned to every partition during formating and dosent change till next formating. In ur case it looks like the UUID nunber got changed post installation which caused the grub to fail. For now try using the device id (/dev/sda4) by editing the bootloader while before startup.

Comment: Thank you. 
1.how do i change it? 
2. Why does it happen? How can i prevent this? (I prefer to re install without problem then to install with problem and then fix it